# JS / TS Date object constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, date, datetime

I'm suffering under the ambiguity of the Date object : local time vs UTC.
The problem:

Users can enter the year, month, day, hour, minute that will then be used for a `Date` object:

```
const d1 = new Date(y, mo -1, d, h, m)
```

This creates a new Date for the user input at **UTC**. Whenever I call `d1.toISOString()` it returns the ISO string for **UTC**, not the local, user timezone.

Also, `d1.getHours()` for instance will be in local time, but with `d1.getTimezoneOffset()` added to the values. So

```
d1.getHours() != h
d1.getHours() == h - d1.getTimezoneOffset()
```

How can this be resolved?

I see the following documentation

*Note: Where Date is called as a constructor with more than one argument, the specified arguments represent local time. If UTC is desired, use new Date(Date.UTC(...)) with the same arguments.*

But I can not wrap my head around it how to properly use local and UTC times...

My question:

How shall I properly use `Date` to handle user input and how call the `toISOString` to get local timestamps? I need the string for the local date as specified by the user in ISO format. Not locale, just the numbers. I do not care about the locale output.

Comment: added a question

Comment: why do you have a `-1` in the parameter to the `Date` constructor? Additionally, `new Date() === new Date(Date.now())` so if you have a Unix timestamp, and call `new Date` with it it will generate a localized `Date`

Comment: @Meghan Because months are 0 based when passed to the constructor

Comment: If you want the date as a string in local time, try `d1.toLocaleString()`

Comment: I need the string for the local date as specified by the user in ISO format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
const d1 = new Date(y, mo -1, d, h, m)
```

then:

```
d1.getHours() != h
```

only in cases where one of the following is true:

1. *h* does not exists on that date (e.g. it's in the period of transition from standard to daylight saving time)
2. h < 0
3. h > 23.

The following shows that when none of these are true, then `d.getHours() == h`

```js
let [Y, M, D, h, m, s] = [2018, 0, 1, 15, 30, 15]; // 2018-01-01T15:30:15
var d = new Date(Y, M, D, h, m, s);
console.log(d.getHours() == h);
```

> How shall I properly use Date to handle user input and how call the toISOString to get local timestamps?

Where the Date constructor is called with more than one argument, the values are treated as local. To treat them as UTC, use the *Date.UTC* method:

```
`new Date(Date.UTC(Y, M, D, h, m, s));
```

The *toISOString* method returns a UTC timestamp, always. If you want an ISO 8601 timestamp with a local timezone offset, you should either use a library or write your own function, something like:

```js
function toISOStringLocal(d) {
  // Pad single digit numbers with leading zero
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'') + n}
  // Convert timezoneOffset to HH:mm
  function formatOffset(offset) {
    let sign = offset < 0? '+' : '-';
    offset = Math.abs(offset);
    return sign + z(offset/60|0) + ':' + z(offset%60);
  }
  return d.getFullYear() + '-' + z(d.getMonth()+1) + '-' +
         z(d.getDate()) + 'T' + z(d.getHours()) + ':' +
         z(d.getMinutes()) + ':' + z(d.getSeconds()) +
         formatOffset(d.getTimezoneOffset());              
}

console.log(toISOStringLocal(new Date()));
```

The use of ":" in the offset is required to be consistent with ECMA-262 and should be tolerated by ISO 8601 compliant parsers.